# Ran sudo apt update and shows errors

Tags: updates, dropbox

I am running 21.04
When I run update it shows several errors.
How do I correct them? or should they be ignored?
Thanks Cliff

results of `apt update`

```
Ign:9 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease      
Err:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.227.39.129 80]
Err:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: `eoan` is Ubuntu 19.04, which is not anymore supported. The output also shows bionic (18.04), whereas you said it is 21.04. Please clarify your release. Don't mix repositories between different versions of Ubuntu. Don't make a [FrankenSystem](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you ARE running Ubuntu 21.04...

**Note**: Your system may not have updated/upgraded properly in the past.

**Note**: If you have any difficulties with these instructions, stop, and ask for help.

Edit two files...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
```

Change bionic to hirsute like shown in the above two lines.

Save the file and quit gedit.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list`

```
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main
```

Change eoan to disco like shown in the above line.

Save the file and quit gedit.

`sudo apt update`

Comment: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. This is what is left.

Comment: @Cliff You didn't edit the first two lines and change bionic to hirsute.

Comment: All bionic are now hirsute, The bionic are all # out. Thanks Cliff